# No data reporting for this application —delete or troubleshoot in New Relic

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have installed New Relic as per their setup guide.
The new relic folder is placed in my E:\apache-tomcat-6.0.16\apache-tomcat-6.0.16\webapps\newrelic.
My application is placed in E:\apache-tomcat-6.0.16\apache-tomcat-6.0.16\webapps.
Now I am trying to monitor my application via new Relic but it is throwing -
"Application down error - No data reporting for this application —delete or troubleshoot ".

What is the solution for this problem ?
Is it a problem due to fortiguard firewall ?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the agent might be having an issue connecting to New Relic's collectors.

The log file would be the first place to check for messages which could indicate an issue. You can check the location of your log file in the newrelic.yml configuration file. 
See the guide to setting up the Java agent for Tomcat on Windows: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/frameworks/tomcat-installation-java#h2-tomcat

It's also worth checking that your firewall/network settings are configured to allow traffic to reach New Relic's servers.
The list of IP addresses and ports required are here; https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/new-relic-apm/getting-started/networks

Should this not turn up and information as to why your application is not reporting, you should then contact New Relic support at support.newrelic.com